# Optimization of comparisons between each key in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, fuzzy

So I want to compare each key of a dictionary to each other and if a key happens to be too similar to another key (based on fuzzy similarity), I want to merge those 2 entries together into a single key (so one key gets deleted whereas the values will be added up). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

d is a dictionary with {"labels": [list of sentences]}

```py
    # First I create a new dictionary that has a dictionary as value which includes the key and value
    # of the old dictionary. It feels a bit redundant but afaik you can't loop through a dictionary and 
    # edit it at the same time + you can't edit keys themselves?

    d_new = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        d_new[key] = {"label": key, "sentences": value}


    for key1, key2 in itertools.combinations(d, 2):
        if fuzz.token_set_ratio(key1, key2) >= similarity:
            if len(d_new[key1]["sentences"]) > len(d_new[key2]["sentences"]):
                d_new[key2]["label"] = key1

            # Merge keys
            d_new[key2]["sentences"] = list(set(d_new[key1]["sentences"] + d_new[key2]["sentences"]))
            del d_new[key1]
            continue

    # Prepare output
    result = {}
    for key, value in d_new.items():
        result[value["label"]] = list(set(value["sentences"]))
    return result
```

Comment: If `a` is similar to `b` and `b` is similar to `c`, but `a` and `c` are not sufficiently similar, should they still all be merged? What exactly is `fuzz.token_set_ratio` is doing and is there an alternative that instead of comparing two values creates a "canonical" value, similar to what Stemming does?

Comment: fuzz.token_set_ratio basically just creates a similarity score between two strings based on various factors. The plan is to merge 2 strings if it's something like 'Donald Trump' and 'Trump'. Regarding your example, currently it depends on if either a and b get merged into a or b (which is currently based on value size so size of how many sentences there are in the list) because if it ends up as a and a isn't similar enough to c then those 2 shouldn't merge. I haven't tried it with a canonical value yet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using itertools.combinations, this will result in a non-linear time complexity to loop over the dictionary. but your code seems to be optimized in the way you want it to be and there probably isn't any better way to find similar keys unless you know what similar things you are looking for.

As the other answer said, further optimization depends on token_set_ratio.

You can also experience with dict comprehension to see if you can make the dict creation faster.
for example:

```
{value['lable']:list(set(value['sentences'])) for (key,value) in d_new.items()}
```

suggestion:

due to limited data on what values are there in your keys its hard to say, but if your keys are structured and are based on a pattern and your dict length is large enough, you can brute force for keys since accessing dict keys is O(1) but there is the cost of 'guessing' similar things (for example if your keys are words, you can probably know what words are similar.). but as I said the dict should be huge for this method to be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this can be optimized **depends on the implementation of `token_set_ratio`**.  If `token_set_ratio` is your only heuristic of similarity between the two tokens, and the implementation of `token_set_ratio` is a black box, then this is the most Big O efficient way to calculate similarity.  The reasoning here is that because your only heuristic is a black box, you must test every binary combination to get a similarity score.

If instead, you have a different heuristic that works on a **single token**, then you may be able to precompute a feature score that can help you cluster more efficiently.  You would expect some false positives.

Alternatively, if you know how the original heuristic is computed, then there may be a way to optimize based on the heuristic.  In that case, you should post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a large percentage of the keys that will be merged, it may be worthwhile to implement the combination logic yourself so that keys that have been merged are not checked again.

There is no data to test this but, here's how it could look like:

```
from collections import deque
def mergeKeys(d):
    result = {k:{v} for k,v in d.items()}  # start with nonthing merged
    keys   = deque(d.keys())               # list of remaining keys
    while keys:
        key1 = keys.popleft()              # consume one key 
        nextKeys = deque()                 # track unmerged for next pass
        while keys:
            key1 = keys.popleft()            # consume paired key
            if key2 not in result: continue
            if fuzz.token_set_ratio(key1, key2) >= similarity:
                result[key1].update(result.pop(key2)) # merge
            else:
                nextKeys.append(key2)        # not merged, add to next pass
        keys = nextKeys                    # remaining keys for next pass
    return result
```